# Accidentally Disabled my Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, internet

In trying to fix a weak Wi-Fi signal by updating the wireless drivers, I've managed to break my ability to connect to any wireless connections. The wireless is a RealTek 8821AE and Qualcomm Atheros 8171 for ethernet. Ubuntu will still display all the available wireless connections, but I cannot connect to any of them - it just continues to attempt connecting indefinitely.

I'm a very inexperienced user, and I'm not sure what I actually did to break this, and I entered a whole bunch of commands I didn't fully understand or keep track of. I do think it could be in part at least related to my attempted use of the ndiswrapper program to use the Windows drivers to update my drivers.

Notably, I cannot access my router through the web browser using the gateway address.  I've tried lots of things like rfkill and restarting the network manager and modprobe removal/reinstall of the wifi, but it cannot connect. My Ubuntu is on a dual boot separate HD, and the wifi on the Windows 10 SSD on the same machine works fine (as with all other devices on my home network).

If there is some kernel-level way to reset the Wi-Fi settings to their original state, that would probably work.  Please note I can't access the internet on Ubuntu at all, and if I need to download anything, I'll have to use a USB drive through Windows.  Any help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: You could try getting NetworkManager out of the picture (systemctl disable network-manager)  and working directly with the adapter using another tool. You could try wpa_supplicant with the generic driver (wext), and then wpa_cli just to see if you can talk to the adapter. There's a lot of info about these tools.

Comment: It looks like I never successfully used the Windows drivers.  I did manage to fix this by changing /etc/default/avahi-daemon to AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=1  Somewhere in my fumbling I must have messed it up.  Thanks for the comments and help!